# Populate tables with random data

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm gonna try and explain my issue as simple as I can. I have an assignment to complete where I have to make all kinds of different queries and then optimize them through  different methods(indexes, nested loops etc.). The problem is that for me to achieve the main objective, I need to have thousands of entries in my tables so that the optimization methods actually have a visible effect. These are the two main tables I'm working with:

```
create cluster fact_trip
   (id_trip integer);

create table trip
    (id_trip integer not null,
    driver_mark integer)
    cluster fact_trip(id_trip);
alter table cursa add constraint trip_pk primary key(id_trip);

create table facturi
    (id_factura integer not null,
    price number(6,2) not null,
    discount number(6,2),
    id_trip integer not null)
    cluster fact_trip(id_trip);

alter table facturi add constraint facturi_pk primary key(id_factura);
create index fact_trip_index on cluster fact_trip;
alter table facturi add constraint facturi_trip_fk foreign key(id_trip)
   references trip(id_trip);
```

I know how to make and optimize the queries, but I am not the best at the plSQL side of it, where I need to create a sequence or a loop so that I can populate my tables, especially that such a sequence applied to the table **facturi** needs to depend on the id_trip foreign key. So what I'm asking for is for someone to assist me with such a plSQL code that can randomly fill my two tables with data.

Comment: You don't need PL/SQL. Just use `dbms_random.value()` and multitable inserts: https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/multitable-inserts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use statements like the ones below to create sample data in your tables. The two statements below will put 1000 rows in each table. You can adjust the `LEVEL` on the first insert if you want more or less records.

```sql
INSERT INTO trip
        SELECT CAST (ROWNUM AS INTEGER)                                 AS id_trip,
               CAST (ROUND (DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE (1, 100)) AS INTEGER)     AS driver_mark
          FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1000;

INSERT INTO facturi
    SELECT CAST (ROWNUM AS INTEGER)
               AS id_factura,
           ROUND (DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE (1, 1000), 2)
               AS price,
           CASE WHEN DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE > .5 THEN ROUND (DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE (1, 1000), 2) END
               AS discount,
           t.id_trip
               AS id_trip
      FROM DUAL  d
           LEFT JOIN (  SELECT id_trip
                          FROM trip
                      ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE) t
               ON (1 = 1);
```